# why iptables giving error when using with --src-range

Tags: linux, security, firewall, iptables

I am using iptables v 1.4.8 and used following command but getting one error message on terminal

```
# iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 10.0.4.92-10.0.4.99  -j DROP
```

`modprobe: module 'ip_tables' not found`

Then after this when i am using

```
iptables-save
```

then also seeing the same error.

also when  using

```
iptables -L
```

same error is comming to terminal with the result of `iptables -L` , I am thinking using the --range option giving me this error as I tried other command but not having this error.

But it is working fine but why this error is coming to terminal I can figure out.

Kindly give some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current kernel wasn't built with iptables support (`CONFIG_IP_NF_IPTABLES`), or the module has been erased.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,but how then it is working.

Comment: The command has nothing to do with kernel support.

Comment: Thanks but how one command will work without its core module and how it is blocking with out the internal core part.

Comment: The command has nothing to do with kernel support.

Comment: Thanks that means that module is not needed.am I correct if yes then why this error is coming.To solve this error I have to built with this support.can you give me the path in kernel configuration.

Comment: I don't know where it is; I only use stock kernels.